# "case .. do" with some conditions in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to do something like this:

```
  cust = Repo.get(Customer, id)
  case cust do
    nil ??? or not nil but is_activated == false && registration_date is over 1 month ago?? -> # something1 .....

    custm1 -> # something2
  end
```

If a customer doesn't exist or it they exist but aren't activated **and** their registration date is over 1 month ago --> do something1. If a customer exists --> do something2. How can I encode that via "case", is it possible?

Comment: `case` is for pattern matching (+ guards), which is not what you're doing. Why not use `cond`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you've got a `Customer` struct and that's what `Repo.get(Customer, id)` is going to return (or `nil`). What you're asking for looks like this:

```
cust = Repo.get(Customer, id)
month_ago = (DateTime.utc_now |> DateTime.to_unix) - 60*60*24*30  # approx. 1 month before now
case cust do
  nil ->
    something1()
  %Customer{is_activated: false, registration_date: regged} when month_ago > regged ->
    something1()
  _ ->
    something2()
end
```

What makes this an unnatural-feeling construct IMO is that you're handling `nil` and a subset of non-nil data in the same way. Usually, you're using `case` because you're going to *do* something with the data that you're matching. Like:

```
case cust do
  %Customer{is_activated: false, registration_date: regged, email: email} when week_ago > regged ->
    send_reminder(email, regged)
  %Customer{is_activated: false, registration_date: regged} when month_ago > regged ->
    delete_account(cust)
  %Customer{is_activated: true, sent_thanks: false, email: email} ->
    send_thanks(email)
    Repo.update(Customer, %{cust | sent_thanks: true})
end
```

If what you really want is to test a bunch of complex conditions, you might want either a set of nested `if`s or a `cond`:

```
cust = Repo.get(Customer, id)
cond do
  cust == nil ->
    something1()
  !cust.is_activated && is_old(cust) ->
    something1()
  true ->
    something2()
end
```

[The Elixir documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html) gives more examples and explanation about this distinction.